# JSON-Cannot read property 'img' of undefined

Tags: angular, getjson, ionic3

I have created a JSON file that has data, in Ionic 3 I have fetched them using a provider.

Here is the json file

```json
[
    {
        "teachers": {
            "img":"assets/home/img.png"
        }
    }        
]
```

**Component**

```js
homeds: Home[];

constructor(
    public navCtrl: NavController, 
    public navParams: NavParams, 
    public dataService: DataProvider,
    public loadingCtrl: LoadingController
) {
    this.dataService
        .fetchData()
        .subscribe((data) => {
            this.homeds = data
        })
}
```

**Template**

```html
<ion-col width-50 *ngFor="let home of homeds">
    <img src="{{ home.teachers.img }}" alt="">
</ion-col>
```

When I run this code I get

> Runtime Error
>   Cannot read property 'img' of undefined

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Is it because of the spelling mistake in the component? `homeds`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Elvis/safe navigation operator in your interpolation, like so:

```
<img src="{{ home?.teachers.img }}" alt="">
```

Comment: This works for me <img src="{{ home.teachers?.img }}" alt="">, I have tried to edit the answer but in vain. But thanks.

Comment: I had to change the data to accommodate more data     {
      "teachers": [
          {
            "img":"assets/insta/Janine.png",
            "name":"Janine "
          },{
            "img":"assets/insta/Itzhak.png",
            "name":"Itzhak Perlman"
          }
      ]
    }, on template it doesn't show anything on console I can log the data.